# Trouble with MAC address use in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

From iOS 7.0.2 the MAC address is: 02:00:00:00:00:00. I was saving MAC address on server, so that a user can use my app on single device with one log in and need have new log in credentials for other device. If a user deletes my app and then reinstall on same device, he could use same log in credentials. But now as MAC address is no more available and there is [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) which changes with new install, so I am unable to track it on my server.

Please help me in this regard as I can not find any way to manage tracking.

Comment: Using the MAC address is a bad idea anyway. Why not have the user create an account like pretty much every other web service does? There's even OAuth so you don't have to manage the whole thing yourself. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: user has an account but he has to use app on same device with one account and have to have new account for other device. Therefore I have to keep track of account, password and mac address

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=8222013a):

MAC addresses in iOS 7
August 22, 2013
If your apps use the MAC address to identify an iOS device, the system will return the same static value for all devices running iOS 7. Please update your apps to use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice. If you need an identifier for advertising purposes, use the advertisingIdentifier property of ASIdentifierManager.

So [ODIN1](http://code.google.com/p/odinmobile/) as an advertisement identifier is broken as well. Maybe [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) is still working, but I did not test that.